# R Markdown: knit a pdf and exclude title-page

Tags: r, pdf, yaml, markdown

is it possible to exclude the title page from the knitted pdf?

my current yaml header looks as follows:

```
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
header-includes: 
- \pagenumbering{gobble}

---
```

when i knit the pdf it however still adds a first blank page to the pdf for the yaml information.
is it possible to exclude the title page from the knitted document? with something like *preserve_yaml = FALSE*?
(Of course I could just delete the blank first page in de pdf, but im going to generate this document on a regular basis, so it would improve the process quit a bit...)

thanks for any hints / help!

Comment: What R and knitr version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header-includes: 
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
```

this should tell pandoc to not process the title page.

Comment: friendly remider to close the question if your satisfied with the answer :)